# Reduce the Complexity of this Distribution to something Sensible?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So in the Roleplaying Stack, we were posed with an absurd sequence of rolling dice to achieve a given result.

> *Roll a D20.
>
>   Roll that many D20's.
>
>   Roll that many D12's.
>
>   Roll that many D10's.
>
>   Roll that many D8's.
>
>   Roll that many D6's.
>
>   Roll that many D4's.
>
>   Flip that many Coins.*
>
> *The number of heads flipped is the damage you deal.*

So I'll give an example just so it's clear how this works.

1. First, we'd roll a D20, or a twenty-sided die, [1, 20]. Suppose we get the result 7.
2. Then, we'd roll 7d20, or 7 twenty-sided dice, which are summed together. Suppose we get 73.
3. We'd then roll 73d12, or 73 twelve-sided dice [1, 12]. Suppose we roll 430.
4. We roll 430d10, or 430 ten-sided dice [1, 10]. Suppose we roll 2605.
5. We roll 2605d8, or 2605 eight-sided dice [1, 8]. Suppose we roll 12000.
6. We roll 12000d6, or 12000 six-sided dice [1, 6]. Suppose we roll 42008.
7. We roll 42008d4, or 42008 four-sided dice [1, 4]. Suppose we roll 100050.
8. Finally, we'd flip 100050 coins [0, 1] and add up all the Heads we get. We'll suppose that we roll exactly 50000 heads, just to cap it all off.

So executing this absurd chain of events is at least describable. It's not practical, given the number of dice a user would eventually need to roll, but we can at least imagine the process.

But now I want to apply statistics to this distribution, and I haven't the faintest clue where to start. I'd like to get important information about how this set is distributed, like its mean, mode, median, etc., potentially even the specific odds of each outcome in the set [0, 9216000] of the number of heads we could eventually flip.

So far, my attempts to try to solve this issue programmatically have been stymied by the computational complexity of the problem. My method involved building arrays of probabilities at each step of the way, to then combine further on to build a final array where each of the 9,216,001 unique outcomes were represented with relatively accurate odds of having flipped that number of heads.

To show this as an example, we'll reduce the problem down to just a d4, followed by that number of d4s, so that our table is relatively small:

\begin{array}{r|llll}
\textbf{1d4→} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} \\
\textbf{Xd4↓} & .25 & .25 & .25 & .25 \\ \hline
\text{1d4 - 1} & 0.25\\
\text{1d4 - 2} & 0.25\\
\text{1d4 - 3} & 0.25\\
\text{1d4 - 4} & 0.25\\
\text{2d4 - 2} &   & 0.0625\\
\text{2d4 - 3} &   & 0.125\\
\text{2d4 - 4} &   & 0.1875\\
\text{2d4 - 5} &   & 0.25\\
\text{2d4 - 6} &   & 0.1875\\
\text{2d4 - 7} &   & 0.125\\
\text{2d4 - 8} &   & 0.0625\\
\text{3d4 - 3} &   &  & 0.015625\\
\text{3d4 - 4} &   &  & 0.046875\\
\text{3d4 - 5} &   &  & 0.09375\\
\text{3d4 - 6} &   &  & 0.15625\\
\text{3d4 - 7} &   &  & 0.1875\\
\text{3d4 - 8} &   &  & 0.1875\\
\text{3d4 - 9} &   &  & 0.15625\\
\text{3d4 - 10} &   &  & 0.09375\\
\text{3d4 - 11} &   &  & 0.046875\\
\text{3d4 - 12} &   &  & 0.015625\\
\text{4d4 - 4} &   &   &  & 0.00390625\\
\text{4d4 - 5} &   &   &  & 0.015625\\
\text{4d4 - 6} &   &   &  & 0.0390625\\
\text{4d4 - 7} &   &   &  & 0.078125\\
\text{4d4 - 8} &   &   &  & 0.12109375\\
\text{4d4 - 9} &   &   &  & 0.15625\\
\text{4d4 - 10} &   &   &  & 0.171875\\
\text{4d4 - 11} &   &   &  & 0.15625\\
\text{4d4 - 12} &   &   &  & 0.12109375\\
\text{4d4 - 13} &   &   &  & 0.078125\\
\text{4d4 - 14} &   &   &  & 0.0390625\\
\text{4d4 - 15} &   &   &  & 0.015625\\
\text{4d4 - 16} &   &   &  & 0.00390625\\
\end{array}

Which, when these two arrays are properly multiplied together, gives

\begin{array}{r|ll}
\textbf{Outcomes} & \textbf{Odds} & \textbf{Fraction} 
\\ \hline
\text{1} & 0.0625 & \text{64/1024}\\
\text{2} & 0.07813 & \text{80/1024}\\
\text{3} & 0.09766 & \text{100/1024}\\
\text{4} & 0.12207 & \text{125/1024}\\
\text{5} & 0.08984 & \text{92/1024}\\
\text{6} & 0.0957 & \text{98/1024}\\
\text{7} & 0.09766 & \text{100/1024}\\
\text{8} & 0.09277 & \text{95/1024}\\
\text{9} & 0.07813 & \text{80/1024}\\
\text{10} & 0.06641 & \text{68/1024}\\
\text{11} & 0.05078 & \text{52/1024}\\
\text{12} & 0.03418 & \text{35/1024}\\
\text{13} & 0.01953 & \text{20/1024}\\
\text{14} & 0.00977 & \text{10/1024}\\
\text{15} & 0.00391 & \text{4/1024}\\
\text{16} & 0.00098 & \text{1/1024}\\ \hline
\textbf{Average} & 6.250
\end{array}

<sup>Could be easily used to find Mode (4), Median (6), Mean (6.25) and so on.</sup>

This works fine for small sets, but as with the motivating example, this approach is too computationally expensive for larger sets. So clearly, I need a different approach.

What kinds of methods are available to try to reduce the complexity of a problem like this, and how do those methods work?

---

I'm editing this post because the only answer that has thusfar been posted doesn't really satisfy my needs.

Short version: I don't "speak" generalized mathematics. I can't take an arbitrary formula and analyze it to get stats I want. Like, I'm operating with confidence (because I don't have enough experience with the math to actually know) that the answer describing a general formula for my problem is correct.

So what do I do with that? Can I plug it into Wolfram Alpha to get the Median, Mode, etc.? If so, how?

Let's suppose, for the sake of argument, I wanted to find out the exact odds that 1000 heads are flipped, given my criterion. How can I use that formula to find that out? And can that be done in a sensible manner for every possible outcome, using that formula?

Comment: If you don't speak "generalized math" then it really depends on how exact you want things to be: (1) The exact $P(n)$ for $n$ heads will certainly be a formula too complicated to handle. (2) The exact $P(1000)$ would be so close to zero that (if this were for an actual RPG) you don't care about its exact value. (3) If you want "good but inexact" statistics, then (my gut feel) Monte Carlo will give you very good estimates on mode, median, and some bins of numbers with where the prob is high. (But it'd be hard to simulate any rare event, i.e. the very long thin tail of large but rare $n$)

Comment: Finally, (4) you can write a program to enumerate all cases and calculate exact $P(n)$ for all $n$.  If you truly care about $P(n)$ for every single $n$, then calculating them all together will be faster than calculating each one separately using whatever complicated formula someone else comes up with.  Of course, this assumes you have data types of sufficient precision (or are exact) and enough memory and don't care about the running time.

Comment: @antkam I have attempted to try to solve the problem programmatically, and although various attempts have been more successful than others, I do keep running into issues with memory. One such attempt, where I simply tried to generate the distribution for the first three terms (`d20(d20(d12))`) ate up 15 Gigabytes of Memory and took 3 hours to run. Attempts using slightly less precise math only took a few minutes and ~100MB of memory, but the problem still gets exponentially more complex for each additional term.

Comment: @antkam I'm currently working on a version that pares down the memory use to only the bare essentials, which I *think* will mean it never consumes more than a gigabyte of memory, but I also anticipate the runtime complexity will be astronomical, unlikely to be solvable without the use of a super computer. We shall see though, and that version ought to at least have the potential of being multithreaded...

Comment: But seriously, why do you need the exact $P(n)$ for every single $n$?  You said you would like an exact formula, but any "formula" anyone can come up with will have so many summations and products etc that it is effectively a multiple-loop program anyway.  And that just calculates one $P(n)$.  OTOH I would guess Monte-Carlo gives good estimates of the median and mode.

Comment: @antkam My Monte-Carlo simulations didn't seem especially trustworthy. I've done distributions on smaller versions of this problem (i.e. reducing the input set to something that doesn't explode the RAM use) that produced very curious distribution shapes, and the monte-carlo attempts to produce those distributions worked very poorly. Most of the potential outcomes taper off relatively slowly, so a Monte-Carlo simulation having to accurately represent every single outcome might require literal months of runtime.

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain the probabilities for your d4-d4 example via the [probability generating function (pgf)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) 
$$
p(x)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^4 \left(\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j=1}^4 x^j\right)^i,$$ which expands to $$(64 x+80 x^2+100 x^3+125 x^4+92 x^5+98 x^6+100 x^7+95 x^8+80 x^9+68 x^{10}+52 x^{11}+35 x^{12}+20 x^{13}+10 x^{14}+4 x^{15}+x^{16})/1024,$$ in agreement with your table. You can calculate moments via differentiation.  For example, the mean is $p'(1)=25/4$, as you had computed.

For the original problem, the pgf would be
$$p(x)=
\frac{1}{20} \sum_{i_1=1}^{20} \left(
\frac{1}{20} \sum_{i_2=1}^{20} \left(
\frac{1}{12} \sum_{i_3=1}^{12} \left(
\frac{1}{10} \sum_{i_4=1}^{10} \left(
\frac{1}{8} \sum_{i_5=1}^{8} \left(
\frac{1}{6} \sum_{i_6=1}^{6} \left(
\frac{1}{4} \sum_{i_7=1}^{4} \left(
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i_8=1}^{2} 
x^{i_8}
\right)^{i_7}
\right)^{i_6}
\right)^{i_5}
\right)^{i_4}
\right)^{i_3}
\right)^{i_2}
\right)^{i_1}
.$$

Comment: So if I extend this answer to use my original set, is that going to yield useful information to me? Can I use it to extract the information I want, like the Median, Mode, etc.?

Comment: To get the mean, you can calculate $p'(1)$.  To get the probability of obtaining exactly 1000 heads, extract the coefficient of $x^{1000}$.  In WolframAlpha, this is `SeriesCoefficient[p[x],{x,0,1000}]`

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 statistics that are not too bad to calculate in this example:  the mean and the variance.  As far as I can tell, the rest require significant computing power.

I will start by defining my terms.

Let $m$ be which step we are in.  Step 1 is the roll of a single d20, step 2 is the roll of a variable amount of d20s, step 3 is the roll of a variable amount of d12s, etc...

Let $n$ be a count of which SPECIFIC roll in that step, which can take values from 1 to the sum from the previous step.

Let $X_{m,n}$ be the random variable that represents the number rolled in the nth roll during the mth step of the process.  Each $X_{m,n}$ will be independent of each other.  Their distribution will be dependent on the value of m with a [discrete uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution).

$$X_{m,n}\sim U_D(a_m,b_m)$$

Let $Y_m$ be the total of all rolls for the mth step.  For example, $Y_4$ would be the total of all of the d10 rolls.  Therefore, we have the following:

$$Y_m = \sum_{n=1}^{Y_{m-1}} X_{m,n}$$

With all my terms defined, I can get into the calculation.  My goal is to use the [Law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) and the [Law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance).  In order to do so, I will write $E(Y_m)$ and $\text{Var}(Y_m)$ in terms of the previous step, which is $Y_{m-1}$.

Recall that the number of rolls or flips in the sum is the same as the previous sum.  Therefore, by the linearity of expectation and $X_{m,n}$ being iid for identical m:

$$E(Y_m\mid Y_{m-1}) = \sum_{n=1}^{Y_{m-1}} E(X_m) = Y_{m-1} \cdot E(X_m)$$

Similarly, since the variance of a sum of independent random variables is the sum of the individual variances:

$$\text{Var}(Y_m\mid Y_{m-1}) = \sum_{n=1}^{Y_{m-1}} \text{Var}(X_m) = Y_{m-1} \cdot \text{Var}(X_m)$$

We can now apply those with the Law of total expectation and the Law of total variance to make iterative formulas for each.

$$E(Y_m) = E[E(Y_m\mid Y_{m-1})] = E[Y_{m-1} \cdot E(X_m)] = E(Y_{m-1})\cdot E(X_m)$$

For the variance, the calculation is similar:

$$\text{Var}(Y_m) = E[\text{Var}(Y_m\mid Y_{m-1})] + \text{Var}[E(Y_m\mid Y_{m-1})] \\ = E[Y_{m-1} \cdot \text{Var}(X_m)] + \text{Var}[Y_{m-1} \cdot E(X_m)] \\ = E(Y_{m-1})\cdot \text{Var}(X_m) + \text{Var}[Y_{m-1}]\cdot [E(X_m)]^2$$

The $E(X_m)$ is squared because $\text{Var}(aY) = a^2\text{Var}(Y)$ when $a$ is a constant.

Now that we have the iterative formula, we just need a base case to get started.  In the very first step we have exactly 1 die in the sum.  Therefore, I think the easiest base case would be to define $E(Y_0)=1$ and $\text{Var}(Y_0)=0$.  With an expected value of 1 and a variance of 0, that means we would always have 1 roll to deal with at the beginning.  Our values of $(a_m,b_m)$ for the distributions of $X_m$ will come directly from the text of the problem.  Most of them go from 1 to the number of sides on the die, however in the last step it will go from 0 to 1.

From this point, I used a spreadsheet to perform the iterative calculation to find $E(Y_8)$, and $\text{Var}(Y_8)$.  I created 7 columns:  m, E(Y_m), Var(Y_m), a_m, b_m, E(X_m), and Var(X_m).  I filled in the m column with values from 0 to 8 to represent the base case and the 8 steps to the problem.  I started with the base case, where in the row with m=0, I put in 1 for E(Y_m) and 0 for Var(Y_m).  I filled in the a_m and b_m columns with the range for the discrete uniform distribution at each step from 1 to 8.

As to the formulas, I filled in formulas for E(Y_m) and Var(Y_m) based on my iterative formulas in this answer, and I filled in formulas for E(X_m) and Var(X_m) based on the discrete uniform distribution, based on the values of a_m and b_m.

In the end, the final mean calculated to be $E(Y_8)=77,597.05078125$, and the final variance calculated to be $\text{Var}(Y_8)=2,007,126,628.99956$.  With how large the variance is, it is probably easier just to share the standard deviation, which is $\sqrt{\text{Var}(Y_8)} = 44800.9668310803$.

Those values are not FULL precision, because I used Microsoft Excel, which does not have arbitrary precision.  However, those values should be precise enough that you don't need to worry about rounding errors.

Here is a screenshot of the spreadsheet so you can see the results of all the calculations:

[Spreadsheet Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OprCq.png)

Comment: The formula you get for the expectation (that the expected final total is the product of the expectations of each die/coin) is also known as Wald's Equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation).